# How would I solve for all the zeros in the first quadrant of: $f(z)=z^2+iz+2+i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How would I answer this question using the example in the picture? I think I need to look at different segments of the line, but I am not sure how to find those. Any explanation is helpful as I am really lost in this section of complex!

[image]

Comment: Jus use the quadratic formula.  $z^2 + iz + (2 + i) = 0\implies \frac {-i \pm \sqrt{-1 -4(2+i)}}2$.

Comment: If you want to use the argument principle just note that on the real axis the argument is $\tan^{-1}\frac{x+1}{x^2+2}$ [which runs from $\tan^{-1}\frac12$ to $0$; on the arc it increases by $2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}$; on the imaginary axis it is $\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2-y-y^2}$ [which runs from $\pi$ up to $2\pi$ at $y=1$, then to $2\pi+\tan^{-1}\frac12$]. But all this needs checked out if it's to be a solution.